# Sculpting Symmetry not working

Tags: sculpting, mirror, osx

I am taking a course currently and part of the sculpting portion includes symmetric application, but the sculpting is not being mirrored along any axis. You can see my settings in the image below:

[image]

Comment: where is the origin of your object? You may need to recenter it

Comment: The x & y are at 0, but the z is offset such that the base of the object is flat on the positive side of the z plane

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, is your origin (little orange dot) on the center of your object? If not, in Edit mode select what is supposed to be the center, like for example the tip of the nose, press shift S > Cursor to selected, then back in Object mode press shift ctrl alt C > Origin to 3D Cursor. Then try again. It might be the problem but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ooohhh, sorry. It's the orange dot. I'll go and try those steps.

Comment: If your object is already in the center where you want it, you can just press Ctrl+A and select Location. the orange dot of the object will then move to 0,0,0,0

Comment: @moonboots I'm still having issues. I'm getting it to mirror, but not it's a strange offset.

Comment: maybe apply its rotation in Object mode? (ctrl A)

Comment: @moonboots I finally found it! It was a mix of what you've suggested and realizing that the my object had been moved (rotated/shifted, etc). So once I applied the transforms (Tools menu panel>Physics>Apply Transforms), then set the orange dot, it worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!